# From few hours we are getting NO_AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS error

Tags: bluesnap

Have a support ticket logged in, but in case anyone know something about this error. 
It happens when trying to submit payment form with hosted fields. I have tried with few from the testing cards and on more than one sandbox account same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. We were sending the payment with a really large amount to charge the credit card. So that was the problem in case someone have that error - check what you are trying to charge your users.